# Increasing number of workers - loss of performance

Tags: matlab, cpu, cpu-usage, parfor

if I type `lscpu` in the command-line:

```
CPU(s):              4
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
```

so I have 2 physical cores.

I have no background on parallel computing, but I need it for my purposes. So, since I am a MatLab user, I'm interested in `parfor` loops, but I need to understand what is really going on.

I've red from MatLab documentation, that **default number of workers is one per physical CPU core using a single computational thread**, and also that this choice optimize performance. What I want to understand is how the number of workers affects the performance:

To see this, I tried to run (inspired by [this](https://it.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/scale-up-parfor-loops-to-cluster-and-cloud.html)) the following standard piece of code, changing the number of workers in the `parpool` line.

```
m = 500;
A = randn(m);
N  = 200;
parpool(1); 
tic
x = zeros(1,N);
parfor i=1:N
    x(i) = max(abs(eig(A)));
end
toc
```

and I measure with tic-toc the time taken.

With 1 worker: `% Elapsed time is 26.534430 seconds.`

With 2 workers: `% Elapsed time is 14.528462 seconds.`

With 3 workers: `% Elapsed time is 14.403359 seconds.`

With 4 workers: `% Elapsed time is 17.946775 seconds.`

If I go on with the workers, it takes more time.

I have two questions:

1. I would expect to have the best performance with 2 workers: **why with 3 workers I have still good results?**
2. **Why more workers implies more time?**

Comment: N is too small to test that. there is a lot of overhead with parfor. try N=4000....

Answer (score 2):

The gain in speed is not linear (*double the number of workers, so half the computational time require* is **wrong**). This due to an (almost) constant overhead, in which an underlying scheduler needs to break up the problem in chuncks and organize the distribution -- and eventually join the results again. So you will experience a margin benefit. Have a look at [Gustafson's law on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Amdahl's_law_and_Gustafson's_law).

It becomes worse if the problems are not independent so that the individual workers need to communicate with each other. The slowest worker slowdown the other workers eating up your overall speed-up.

Nevertheless, there is (almost) always an improvement if your switch to `parpool` -- the question is if it is worth it...

BTW, there is no benefit in hyperthreading as MATLAB simply does not use it. If it occupies a CPU with calculations, there is no advantage in registering a second thread that also want to perform calculations on this CPU...

Now, in your particular case: you have a maximum of four workers. However, if you use all four, your system may freeze. Plus there is no way that the background tasks of the system with higher priority can be bypass your calculations on a fee core, so the calculations will get interrupted. Therefore, it is unlikely that this is your optimal setting for your `parpool` -- I like to recommend to always use all-1 core as maximum.

This is all independent from the question whether this is a reasonable number of test to back-up your results statistically.

Comment: " I like to recommend to always use all-1 core as maximum." I don't understand what you mean  with this. Do you mean to use **1 worker x physical core", (as suggested from MatLab) ?

Comment: So, to answer my *second* question: "more workers => more time" because the scheduler need to divide the work and send it to each worker, and this is the reason of the slow down, right?

Comment: you are almost there: the scheduler needs more time and if you use all cores, your operation system will need to interrupt the MATLAB-tasks to perform their own tasks (respond to your mouse movements, security scanner etc). That is the reason why you should use not more than 3 workers if you have 4 cores

Comment: so this answer my second question, and also the first actually. But why do you mention 4 cores? I have two physical cores, not four. So, how many workers should I choose? I think just 2 workers, but please let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Sorry my bad. if you have two workers, there is absolutely no benefit in increasing the number of workers above 2 (actually i thought MATLAB would prevent this). if you use parallel computing at all, don't though your computer and minimize other programs CPU times by closing everything that you can...I would just forget parallel computing for 2 CPUs

Comment: I agree with you: 2 cores are just not enough to see a great benefit. Just one last question, as I have some difficulties in understanding **what** a worker actually is. If I had 4 cores, and I run a parallel pool with 2 workers, will I have 2 cores x workers?

Comment: no a worker is basically a threat from MATLAB. It is an instance of your problem. If you have 2 workers, you `parfor` is divided into 2 loops. Now, if you have just one core, first the first worker calculates a bit until the scheduler forces it to stop. It saves its intermittent results and the scheduler allows the second worker to calculate a but until it decides that its the turn of the first worker again... this goes on until both worker have solved their problem. Now you see that there is no benefit in having more workers than cores;)

Comment: Thanks, it's everything clearer now. So, basically, the main problem with "more workers than cores" is that these workers do not work on **distinct** physical cores. For instance, in your example, we have 2 workers **on** the same core. And therefore, they do can't run in "true" parallel.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I thing I've got it now, do I?